# Share drives time out

Tags: active-directory, network-drive

I have a client that wants their users to be able to be in their network drives for long periods of time without being timed out and having to sign back in.

Currently the users sign in with their Windows credentials for the first time and then about 4 hours later they will have to sign in again. Is there a way to make this time longer? Network drives are pushed and mapped by group policy.

So far I've tried the following without success:

- I have created a new group policy for the drive mapping
- I have turned disabled user account time out. This works for Windows itself (it doesn't go to sleep) but does not seem to have an effect on the network drives.
- I have also tried the following `NET CONFIG SERVER /AUTODISCONNECT:-1` to disable automatic time out.

The issue seems to have occurred after their old DC crashed and a new DC was implemented which makes me think its something with their policies or AD syncing.
The issue seems to be the same if the users are in the office or working over VPN.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: BigBob, can you also edit your question to include what you've looked into yourself already? This prevents that users suggest something that you've tried already and didn't work for some reason (and it shows that you've put some effort into solving your problem).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Do you have control over the server that host the network drives? Perhaps you can change the (samba) configuration there?

Comment: Yes i do have control over there server I will give this a shot just not sure where this setting would be located.